# Cut selected data from daily precipitation CSV files

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file contain of daily precipitation with (253 rows and 191 column daily) so for one year I have 191 * 365 column. 
I want to extract data for certain row and column that are my area of interest example `row 20` and `column 40` for the first day and the `2,3,4 ... 365 days` has the same distance between the column.
I'm new in python, is there any way that I can extract the data and store it in a new csv for a certain row and column for one year? 
Thanks

Comment: usually you slurp the csv into an array, then you do whatever you want with that array, so... yes?

Comment: Do your CSV files have a header row?

Comment: See [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get value from certain row and column you can try smth like this:

```
from itertools import islice

def get_value(f, row, col):
    line = next(islice(f, row - 1, row))
    values = line.split(',')
    return values[col - 1]

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    print(get_value(f, 10, 4))
```

Comment: `line.split(',')` While this might work for this specific file, it's not safe in general - single values can have commas, which is done by quoting the value

Answer (score 0):

Apart from extracting the data, the first thing you need to do is **rearrange your data**.

As it is now, 191 **columns** are added every day. To do that, the whole file needs to be parsed (probably in memory, data growing every day), data gets added to the end of each row, and everything has to be fully written to disk again.

Usually, to add data to a csv, rows are added at the end of the file. No need to parse and rewrite the whole file each time.

On top of that, most software to read csv files starts having problems when the number of columns gets higher.

So it would be a lot better to add the daily data as rows at the end of the csv file.

While we're at it: assuming the 253 x 191 is some sort of grid, or at least every *cell* has te same data type, this would be a great candidate for binary storage (not sure how/if Python can handle that).

All data could be stored in it's binary form resulting in a fixed length *field/cell*. To access a field, it's position could simply be calculated and there would be no need to parse and convert all the data each time. Retrieving data would be almost instant.

Answer (score 0):

I already managed to do the cutting with this script after read some examples and try it

```
`import netCDF4 as nc
pixel = [[1,36,77],[2,37,77],[3,35,78],[4,36,78],[5,37,78],[6,38,78],[7,39,78],[8,40,78],[9,35,79],[10,36,79],[11,37,79],[12,38,79],[13,39,79],[14,40,79],[15,35,80],[16,36,80],[17,37,80],[18,38,80],[19,35,81],[20,36,81],[21,37,81],[22,36,82]]
print pixel
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('D:\RCP45\Hujan_Harian') if isfile(join('D:\RCP45\Hujan_Harian',f))]
print onlyfiles
folder = 'D:\RCP45\Hujan_Harian\\'
fout = open ("D:\My Documents\precipitation.txt", "w")
for j in range (0,len(onlyfiles)): 
    filename = onlyfiles[j]
    print filename
    tahun = filename[0:4]
    print tahun
    from scipy.io import netcdf
    f1 = netcdf.netcdf_file(folder+filename,'r')
    print (f1.variables)
    jlh_hari = int(len(f1.variables['time_bnds'][:]))
    print jlh_hari
    output = []
    for h in range (0,(jlh_hari)):
        for i in range (0,22):
            x=pixel[i][1]
            y=pixel[i][2]
            pr=f1.variables['pr'][h,x,y]
            fout.write(str(pixel[i][0]) + ', , ' + str(tahun) + ', ' + str(pr) + '\n')
        fout.write('\n')
    print output`
```